# Node.js Async mapLimit and memory

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

SOLVED, see the answer please.

I have a list of urls I fetch using request and for some reason I am unable to save more than 1720 records into my database when I try to fetch 2000 or more URL's at a time.

If I try 1000 to 2000 and 2000 to 3000, I get 3000 results in total. But when I try 1000 to 3000 or 4000 to 6000, my script stops after fetching the 1720th result.

What could be the reason for that?

I use mapLimit in order to limit concurrent connections.

```
app.get('/asynctest', function(req, res) {
  var people = [];
  for (var a = 1000; a < 3000; a++) {
    people.push("http://www.example.com/" + a + "/person.html");
  }

  async.mapLimit(people, 20, function(url, callback) {
    // iterator function
    var options2 = {
      url: url,
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': req.headers['user-agent'],
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      }
    };

    request(options2, function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        async.series([
          // add this person into database
          function(callback) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            var name = entities.decodeHTML($('span[itemprop="name"]').text());
            new person({
              name: name,
              url: url
            }).save();
            callback();
          },

          function(callback) {
            async.waterfall([

              function(callback) {
                var $ = cheerio.load(body);
                var jobs = $('span[itemprop="jobtitle"]').length;
                if (jobs == 0) {
                  console.log("no job");
                  var jobsArr = 0;
                } else {
                  var jobsArr = [];
                  for (var aa = 0; aa < jobs; aa++) {
                    jobsArr.push(entities.decodeHTML($('span[itemprop="jobtitle"]').eq(aa).text()));
                  }
                }

                callback(null, jobsArr);
              },

              function(jobsArr, callback) {
                if (jobsArr == 0) {
                  console.log("this person has no jobs");
                } else {

                  async.map(jobsArr, function(jobs, callback) {
                    personRole.where('job_name', jobs).fetch({
                      require: true
                    }).then(function(data1) {
                      data1 = data1.toJSON();
                      person.where('url', url).fetch().then(function(data2) {
                        data2 = data2.toJSON();
                        new personPersonRole({
                          person_id: data2.id,
                          personrole_id: data1.id
                        }).save();
                      });
                    }).catch(function(err) {
                      new personRole({
                        job_name: jobs
                      }).save().then(function(data3) {
                        data3 = data3.toJSON();
                        person.where('url', url).fetch().then(function(data4) {
                          data4 = data4.toJSON();
                          new personPersonRole({
                            person_id: data4.id,
                            personrole_id: data3.id
                          }).save();
                        });
                      });
                    });
                  });
                }
                callback(null, "yes");
              }
            ], function(err, result) {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              }
            });
            callback();
          }
        ], function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("err3");
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.log("err4");
      }
    });
    callback();
  });
});
```

EDIT #2

The following code is also problematic, adds only 1747 records and it stops after that. If I stop my node app and start again, it also stops at 1747.

```
var person = require('./models').person;

app.get('/asynctest', function(req, res) {
  var people = [];
 for (var a = 18000; a < 20000; a++) {
    people.push("random url");
  }

  async.mapLimit(people, 20, function(url, callback) {
    new person({
      name: "YES",
      url: url
    }).save();
    callback();
  });
});
```

db.js

```
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8889,
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'mydatabase',
    charset: 'utf8'
  },
  pool: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100
  }
});

var db = require('bookshelf')(knex);
module.exports = db;
```

models.js

```
var person = db.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'people'
});

module.exports = {
 person : person
};
```

---

EDIT #3

Okay, I think I've found the solution.

> 18K-18.5K - no problem
>
> 18K-19K - no problem
>
> 18K-19.7K - no problem
>
> 18K-20K - RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at new Object
>   (native)

I just wrapped my callbacks into a wrapper, like below.

```
async.setImmediate(function () {
  callback();
});

  app.get('/async22', function(req, res) {
    var people = [];
    for (var a = 18000; a < 20000; a++) {
      people.push("yes");
  }

  async.mapLimit(people, 20, function(url, callback) {
    new person({
      name: "YES",
      url: url
    }).save();
      async.setImmediate(function () {
        callback();
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Looking at the question title, I assume you suspect this is an issue with memory. Why do you think so? Do you see high memory usage when you run the script? (you can check with `top` if you're on linux/osx or in the windows task manager). 

Also when you say "my script stops" - what does it actually mean, do you get some error?

Comment: I checked it out via top till it hit the 1720th record. I don't see any errors, it just stops adding records into my database and uses 0% CPU at this moment.

Comment: What about memory usage, does it use a lot of memory? And when it "just stops" - is it hangs or execution terminates? (in the latter case you should see some output in the console)

Comment: It just hangs. Memory usage is quite low ~400mb at max, actually, but I wonder whether it is related to Node.js (Array limit) or not.

Comment: How do you conclude that it hangs? Does it stop responding to the requests from the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was in front of my eyes all the time, actually this solution isn't unique, it's already included async library's database.

https://github.com/caolan/async#common-pitfalls-stackoverflow

Here's how you do it.

```
async.setImmediate(function () {
  callback();
});
```

Example

```
app.get('/async22', function(req, res) {
    var people = [];
    for (var a = 18000; a < 20000; a++) {
      people.push("yes");
  }

  async.mapLimit(people, 20, function(url, callback) {
    new person({
      name: "YES",
      url: url
    }).save();
      async.setImmediate(function () {
        callback();
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Glad you solved it, so it was a StackOverflow error )))

Answer (score 1):

This is still not an answer, but it is too big for the comment.

I suggest to reduce the code to some minimal example and try if it works (example is below and it works for me).

Second thing - is to add a monitoring route (see the `/apptest` below), so you can check if you app still works and the processing progress.

If the minimal sample works, start to gradually add more code with your logic to it and check if it still works.

The code, server.js:

```
var util = require('util');
var express = require('express');
var async = require('async');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var app = express.createServer();
app.successCount = 0;
app.errorCount = 0;

app.get('/apptest', function(req, res) {
  res.send(
    util.format(
      'I am OK, successCount: %s, errorCount: %s',
      app.successCount, app.errorCount
    ), 200
  );
});

app.get('/asynctest', function(req, res) {
  var people = [];
  for (var a = 1000; a < 3000; a++) {
    people.push("http://www.example.com/" + a + "/person.html");
  }

  async.mapLimit(people, 20, function(url, callback) {
    // iterator function
    var options2 = {
      url: url,
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': req.headers['user-agent'],
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      }
    };

    request(options2, function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error) {
        console.log('success requesting: ' + options2.url);
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        app.successCount += 1;
      } else {
        console.log(
          'error requesting: %s, error: %s, status: %s',
          options2.url, error, response.statusCode
        );
        app.errorCount += 1;
      }
      callback();
    });
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log(
    "Express server listening on port %d in %s mode",
    app.address().port, app.settings.env
  );
});
```

Dependencies, package.json:

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^1.5.2",
    "cheerio": "^0.19.0",
    "express": "2.5.8",
    "request": "^2.67.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Run the example as `node server.js` and then open http://localhost:3000/asynctest in the browser, you should see `success requesting: xxxx` in the console. While it is running (or when it stops running) - open http://localhost:3000/apptest to check if app is OK and how many urls are processed.

Comment: I edited my question, can you please check edit #2 out? Thank you for your answer, I'm looking into it.

Comment: @salep do you mean the edit `var a = 1000...` vs just `a = 1000...`? The `var a` is correct way to declare it (because you don't need a global variable here), but I think in this case it should not make any difference.

Comment: No, "EDIT #2" part :)

Comment: @salep OK, I see it now. So the whole thing is not related to the network activity. Where do you save the data? Can you also show the code for the `person` object? And how do you check that only 1747 are saved, do you check in the database?

Comment: Yes, I check it via phpMyAdmin. I'm using MySQL, btw. I edited my question again, added some additional details to EDIT #2.

Comment: I solved my problem, it was front of my eyes all the time. I need to use `async.setImmediate(function ()` for my callbacks. Your answer inspired me a lot, thank you.